# Shell command syntax error in for loop in Codefresh

Tags: shell, sh, codefresh

I have below step to go through `for loop`. However I'm getting below synatx error.

Code:

```
steps:
  arti_lib_deploy:
    stage: build image
    type: freestyle
    title: "Deploy Libs to Artifactory"
    image: 'hub.artifactory.gcp.xxxx/curlimages/curl:latest'
    commands:
      - LIB_FOLDERS=["lib1","lib2"]
      - >
        for LIB_FOLDER in "${LIB_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
         echo "FolderName- ${LIB_FOLDER}"
         curl -X GET -kv https://xxxx.service.test/entitlements/effPermissions?permissionId= "${LIB_FOLDER}"
        done
```

Error:

```
Executing command: LIB_FOLDERS=["lib1","lib2"]
[2023-08-06T10:54:14.700Z] ------------------------------
Executing command: for LIB_FOLDER in "${LIB_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
echo "FolderName-${LIB_FOLDER }"
done

[2023-08-06T10:54:14.701Z] /bin/sh: syntax error: bad substitution
[2023-08-06T10:54:15.036Z] Reading environment variable exporting file contents.[2023-08-06T10:54:15.052Z] Reading environment variable exporting file contents.[2023-08-06T10:54:16.224Z] [SYSTEM]
Message
Failed to run freestyle step: Deploy Libs to Artifactory
Caused by
Container for step title: Deploy Libs to Artifactory, step type: freestyle, operation: Freestylestep. 
Failed with exit code: 2
Documentation Link https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/codefresh-yaml/steps/freestyle/
Exit code
2
Name
NonZeroExitCodeError
```

Sh command:

```
 commands:
   - LIB_FOLDERS="lib1 lib2"
   - for LIB_FOLDER in $LIB_FOLDERS;
     do
      echo "FolderName- $LIB_FOLDER"
     done
```

Error:

```
Executing command: LIB_FOLDERS="lib1 lib2"
------------------------------
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "done")
[2023-08-06T23:48:22.532Z] Reading environment variable exporting file contents.
[2023-08-06T23:48:22.543Z] Reading environment variable exporting file contents.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Codefresh, but the `"${LIB_FOLDERS[@]}"` syntax is specific to bash, and `/bin/sh` apparently is not bash on your system (it typically isn't). Either avoid bash-specific features or figure out how to get CodeFresh to use bash rather than `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I tried `sh` command as well (Updated in the question).

Comment: You don't need both the the semicolon and the newline before the `do` keyword, but I don't think that's the problem. Maybe you need to put the command on one line? `for LIB_FOLDER in $LIB_FOLDERS ; do echo "FolderName- $LIB_FOLDER" ; done`

Comment: I'm speculating that each command prefixed by `- ` is sent to `/bin/sh` individually. There may also be a way to get Codefresh to include newlines in a command, but it's not necessary here.

Comment: @KeithThompson One-line works!!!!. Please add as the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/), but your question gives me some vague ideas about how it interacts with the shell.

Your original code has `"${LIB_FOLDERS[@]}"` in one of the commands. That's bash-specific syntax (it expands to all the elements of the `LIB_FOLDERS` array), but the error message indicates that Codefresh uses `/bin/sh`.  Apparently `/bin/sh` is not bash on your system (it typically isn't); perhaps it's ash or dash.

One solution would be to avoid bash-specific commands. Another would be to figure out how to persuade Codefresh to use bash rather than `/bin/sh`. Or you could probably write an external bash script that's invoked as a command.

Your second attempt, after some comments was this:

```
 commands:
   - LIB_FOLDERS="lib1 lib2"
   - for LIB_FOLDER in $LIB_FOLDERS;
     do
      echo "FolderName- $LIB_FOLDER"
     done
```

which gave:

```
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "done")
```

This suggests that each command preceded by `-`  is passed to `/bin/sh` separately. One solution is to write the loop in a single line, for example:

```
 commands:
   - LIB_FOLDERS="lib1 lib2"
   - for LIB_FOLDER in $LIB_FOLDERS ; do echo "FolderName- $LIB_FOLDER" ; done
```

And again, if this gets too complicated, it might be best to put the commands in an external script. Note in particular that `lib1` and `lib2` happen to be single words, so combining them into a string that you then split works. If there were spaces in those folder names, you'd have to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Same code works with multilines in Codefresh as below:

```
commands:
   - LIB_FOLDERS="lib1 lib2"
   - >
     for LIB_FOLDER in $LIB_FOLDERS; 
      do echo "FolderName- $LIB_FOLDER";
     done
```